# Implement an Ajax call using the tags data-*

Tags: javascript, ajax, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

I'm trying to implement an Ajax call using the tags data-* as described at
[jquery-ajax-unobtrusive](https://github.com/aspnet/jquery-ajax-unobtrusive)

I know that I can use a javascript function with $.ajax() but my purpose is to experiment with the tags data-ajax...

I tried this code in the cshtml file

```
<a class="btn btn-primary" data-ajax-url="/Home/AjaxSample" data-ajax="true" data-ajax-success="AjaxSuccess" data-ajax-failure="AjaxError" data-ajax-method="GET">Ajax</a>

// other code...

function AjaxSuccess() { alert('AjaxSuccess'); }
function AjaxError() { alert('AjaxError'); }
```

The browser shows the button of course, but nothing happens when I click it.
I can't discover any error in the browser debugger. Nothing happens apparently.

Intellisense doesn't show the tags data-ajax and friends.
Did I forget to include something?

Are there any complete working examples?

Comment: I think did not install reference for it,using nuget install it and then try

Comment: Thanks Pathik; I added Microsoft.jQuery.Unobtrusive.Ajax and Microsoft.jQuery.Unobtrusive.Validation using NuGet but nothing changes

Comment: Found, It was my mistake! Do not forget to add <script src="~/lib/jquery-ajax-unobtrusive/jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.js"></script> in the _Layout.cshtml

Comment: @Tonyc - I'm getting Intellisense for data-ajax, etc. for an <a> tag, but not on a <form> or <button> tag. Are you seeing the same thing?

Comment: Hi @RyanBuening, yes my intellisense shows only data-ajax for <a> tag. Nothing for <form> or <button>.

Comment: @Tonyc: Can you add the comment as an answer and accept it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer from the comments (since no-one has added it):

```
<script src="~/lib/jquery-ajax-unobtrusive/jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.j‌​s"></script>
<!-- the ~ is to symbolize your project's wwwroot folder
```

Add the above to your master layout with all of your other scripts (`_Layout.cshtml` by default).

What this does is include the jQuery unobtrusive ajax file into all of your pages, so that the main script that does all the work is included.

Before doing this, make sure you have installed the package `Microsoft.Jquery.Unobtrusive.Ajax`